# Update textbox when I do an operation c#

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, textbox, app-config

I have a initial *screen* where I have a **textbox** that show a name that has been extracted from a key of file *app.config*.

[image]

**Initially, the key shows for example 60, and if I do an operation, the key is 3 but I don't know how can I update the text in the textbox that represents that key**. This is my code from where I get the value 3:

```
        string nempresa;
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);

        nempresa = config.AppSettings.Settings["EMPRESA"].Value;

        this.textBoxNombreEmpresa.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Bottom;
        this.textBoxNombreEmpresa.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Bookman Old Style", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.textBoxNombreEmpresa.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.MenuHighlight;
        this.textBoxNombreEmpresa.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 742);
        this.textBoxNombreEmpresa.Multiline = true;
        this.textBoxNombreEmpresa.Name = "textBoxNombreEmpresa";
        this.textBoxNombreEmpresa.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1548, 68);
        this.textBoxNombreEmpresa.TabIndex = 3;
        this.textBoxNombreEmpresa.Text = nempresa;
        this.textBoxNombreEmpresa.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
```

Any idea?

Comment: What do you want it to show instead of 3?

Comment: @xTwisteDx what that variable contains, 3 is what the variable contains, but if I update the variable, I want that the textbox be update too

Comment: make a method `UpdateTextBoxNombreEmpresa(string value)` and make `nempresa` to a property. Then you can call this method inside the setter of the property. This way your textbox will always be filled whenever `nempresa` gets a new value

Comment: Hi, did you solve your problem?

Comment: @MongZhu Hi! still working on it! with a timer maybe this works!

Comment: Hi mate, you haven't accepted this answer, and asked already 2 new ones ;) you are fast in here. Did my answer not help you to solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

1)  make `nempresa` to a property:

```
string nempresa;

public string Nempresa
{
    get { return nempresa; }
    set { nempresa = value; }
}
```

2) make a method `UpdateTextBoxNombreEmpresa(string value)`:

```
void UpdateTextBoxNombreEmpresa(string value)
{
    // put whatever code you want to be executed that is associated
    // with the update in here, (styling, position, size, ect...)
    this.textBoxNombreEmpresa.Text = value;
}
```

3) call the method in the setter:

```
public string Nempresa
{
    get { return nempresa; }
    set 
    {
        nempresa = value; 
        UpdateTextBoxNombreEmpresa(nempresa);
    }
}
```

4) use the property instead of the field:

```
this.Nempresa = whatEverYourValueIs;
```

EDIT: This line has to be of course after the initialization of the textbox!

Comment: Thank you for your time Mong Zhu, Should I have to do this in the designer? (I'm starting with C#)

Comment: @LuckWallace no, you write it into your class of your Forms. The property will be a property of the Form.

Comment: So, I have a form called principal.cs, inside of this form are principal.Designer.cs and principal.resx ... Where should I do? sorry for this question, but I am a beginner with this...

Comment: @LuckWallace in [principal.cs]. Open the designer to see the form and then press the F7 key to jump to the code

Comment: Thank you Mong, but is giving me an error because I am defining two times Nempresa, in the step 1) and in the step 3)

Comment: @LuckWallace step 3 says => **call the method in the setter:** it does not say "create the property again" ;)

Comment: Ok perfect, I am trying it but the textbox doesn't show nothing. What I did is, put all that code where you told me and then this.textBoxNombreEmpresa.Text = this.Nempresa; but this is null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204351/discussion-between-luckwallace-and-mong-zhu).

Comment: @LuckWallace I made a small mistake, it should be `this.textBoxNombreEmpresa.Text = value;` I changed it in my edit